# how to use angular router link on an image to make it as a link to navigate into other component

Tags: angular, routes, navigation

how to make clickable image that navigate into other components in angular ,
this image is placed in navbar as a small profile picture of the current user.

```
      <img ngSrc="{{User.photoUrl ||'./assets/images/default.png'}}" alt="user image" height="40" 
       width="40" priority>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `routerlink` in an `<img>`-element, you can wrap it in an `<a>`-element and apply the router-link to the `<a>`-element:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/route']">
   <img ngSrc="{{User.photoUrl ||'./assets/images/default.png'}}" alt="userimage" height="40" width="40" priority>
</a>
```